# How can I consume a Scala macro/quasiquote for code templates?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I want to generate a bunch of objects at compile time that follow a simple pattern, so I wrote the following macro:

```
object MyMacro {

  def readWrite[T](taName: String, readParse: String => T, label: String, format: T => String): Any = macro readWriteImpl[T]

  def readWriteImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(taName: c.Expr[String], readParse: c.Expr[String => T], label: c.Expr[String], format: c.Expr[T => String]): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    def termName(s: c.Expr[String]): TermName = s.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(s: String)) => TermName(s)
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a string literal")
    }

    c.Expr[Any](q"""
    object ${termName(taName)} extends TypeAdapter.=:=[${implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe}] {
      def read[WIRE](path: Path, reader: Transceiver[WIRE], isMapKey: Boolean = false): ${implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe} =
        reader.readString(path) match {
          case null => null.asInstanceOf[${implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe}]
          case s => Try( $readParse(s) ) match {
            case Success(d) => d
            case Failure(u) => throw new ReadMalformedError(path, "Failed to parse "+${termName(label)}+" from input '"+s+"'", List.empty[String], u)
          }
        }

      def write[WIRE](t: ${implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe}, writer: Transceiver[WIRE], out: Builder[Any, WIRE]): Unit =
        t match {
          case null => writer.writeNull(out)
          case _    => writer.writeString($format(t), out)
        }
    }
    """)
  }
}
```

I'm not sure I have the return value for readWrite and readWriteImpl correct--the compiler complains mightily about some assertion failure!

I'm also not sure how to actually consume this macro.  First I tried (in a separate compilation unit):

```
object TimeFactories {
    MyMacro.readWrite[Duration](
      "DurationTypeAdapterFactory",
      (s: String) => Duration.parse(s),
      "Duration",
      (t: Duration) => t.toString)
}
```

Didn't work. If I tried to reference TimeFactories.DurationTypeAdapterFactory I got an error saying it wasn't found.  Next I thought I'd try assigning it to a val...didn't work either:

```
object Foo {
  val duration = MyMacro.readWrite[Duration](
    "DurationTypeAdapterFactory",
    (s: String) => Duration.parse(s),
    "Duration",
    (t: Duration) => t.toString).asInstanceOf[TypeAdapterFactory]
}
```

How can I wire this up so I get generated code compiled like this:

```
object TimeFactories{
    object DurationTypeAdapterFactory extends TypeAdapter.=:=[Duration] {
      def read[WIRE](path: Path, reader: Transceiver[WIRE], isMapKey: Boolean = false): Duration =
        reader.readString(path) match {
          case null => null.asInstanceOf[Duration]
          case s => Try( Duration.parse(s) ) match {
            case Success(d) => d
            case Failure(u) => throw new ReadMalformedError(path, "Failed to parse Duration from input 'Duration'", List.empty[String], u)
          }
        }

      def write[WIRE](t: Duration, writer: Transceiver[WIRE], out: Builder[Any, WIRE]): Unit =
        t match {
          case null => writer.writeNull(out)
          case _    => writer.writeString(t.toString, out)
        }
    }

// ... More invocations of the readWrite macro with other types for T
}
```

Comment: Maybe read the docs at https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/usecases.html and https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typeproviders.html and look at linked examples. Then the answer will make more sense.

Comment: As it is obvious from the signature, macros are not supposed to be used to generate `object`s, they are supposed to be used to generate __values__, probably of newly created anonymous types. I think you should re-think your approach. Probably it would help to specify your real high-level problem to not get caught in a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also it might help to look at Scala JSON serialization libraries like [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) or [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) that seem to do similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, that you can generate new identifiers using macros and than use them publicly.

Instead, try to replace `object ${termName(taName)} extends TypeAdapter` simply with `new TypeAdapter` and assign invocation of the macro to a val (as in your second example). You will then reference an anonymous (and generated) class stored in a val. Parameter `taName` becomes redundant.